# How to delete a ListItem by Swiping out the element?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to find a Component how to remove my ListItems in my ListView. Actually there is a Module working for iOS [react-native-swipeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipeout)  where you can swipeout the elements. I need the same for Android or atleast something similar.

Maybe someone has figured this out, and could tell me how they solved deleting Items from a ListView in a React Native Android App

Comment: You end up finding anything good?

Comment: I ended up using swipeout for ios and using Material Dialogs for Android which additionally fits the guidelines of each platform

Comment: Beauty! Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 0):

The react native team removed their experimental implementation for the  SwipeableFlatList component (which uses internally a FlatList instead really really deprecated ListView).

I rescued the original code from v0.59 which they removed on v.60 and its available as a npm module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deprecated-react-native-swipeableflatlist)

And theres a good how-to on medium [here](https://medium.com/@rutvikbhatt9/how-to-use-swipeableflatlist-new-react-native-experimental-component-cb792b1c7b0a)